# Insert same MAX value in multiple rows at a time in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a procedure that inserts n rows at a time. 
Each time it should pick up the `MAX(BatchNo)` and insert it along with other columns.

```
Select @maxbatchno = MAX(batchno) from table1;

insert into table1 (name,phone,batchno) 
select name,phone, maxbatchno from #temp;
```

Wouldn't there be concurrency issues with the above query? If there are multiple users trying to run this procedure wouldn't there be duplicates?

Comment: Interesting question.  An identity wouldn't help you here because you want the same Max for multiple rows.  Have you looked into sequences?  Each call would fetch the latest sequence value which wouldn't overlap.

Comment: @TheImpaler I was thinking of something quick and easy fix for now like may be setting isolation level to SERIALIZABLE?

Comment: I don't think SERIALIZABLE will cut it for this one. A full table lock will work, if you don't care about simultaneous users accessing it becoming slow.

Comment: @TheImpaler how do you propose we do that? Need a fix ASAP. We have a demo !

Comment: @TheImpaler WITH (TABLOCKX)?

Comment: You can use `select * from my_table with (tablockx)` inside a transaction. Mind that while the transaction is ongoing (before committing or rolling back), no other user will be able to use the table.

Comment: so if i run `select * from my_table with (tablockx)` at the start of a sql transaction block then that table will locked until the transaction is complete?

Comment: @TheImpaler no other connection will be able to read the table ?

Comment: I haven't tried it lately, but yes I remember that during the transaction any other SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE that uses the table will "wait" until the transaction finishes and releases the table lock.

Comment: @TheImpaler, does that trump the ever popular `with nolock`?

Comment: @TheImpaler that doesnt seem to be working.. I opened two query windows and pasted : `insert into   test values(1),(2)
BEGIN TRANSACTION tran1
declare @maxid int 
select @maxid =  max(id)+1 from test WITH (TABLOCKX);
      
       insert into test values(@maxid)`
And then ran `      COMMIT TRANSACTION tran1
` in both windows one by one and there were duplicate rows inserted

Comment: @TheImpaler my apologies. I wrote wrong script. Its working thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing entities.  You have a "batch" entity, but it is hidden.  If you have a table for that and use the table, you won't have a problem.

I actually assume that you want a NEW batch number, which would be larger than the previous value.  Your version is just re-using the previous value, over and over.  So:

```
create tables batches (
    batchId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    createdAt datetime default getdate()
    -- other columns here could be useful
);

create table @ids (batchId int);

insert into batches
    output inserted.batchId into @ids
    default values;

insert into table1 (name, phone, batchno) 
    select t.name, t.phone, i.batchId
    from #temp t cross join
         @ids i;
```

With this approach, you don't have to worry about concurrency issues.

Note:  You *could* use a sequence instead.  But I think that "batch" is a first-class entity and should have its own table.

Answer (score 0):

(Talking from experience with similar scenarios here)

If you have a demo coming up very soon I would just go with:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;  
BEGIN TRAN;

-- do your stuff here but don't forget the overall error handling...

COMMIT
```

However, as soon as you have the time - perhaps even after this demo - I highly recommend doing some stress testing (multi-threaded!) which incorporate comparing this `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` approach with the results from the more granular `sp_getapplock` approach, which can be used if you *absolutely* want to make sure the inserts are processed single-threaded *and* your expected load is going to be very high. If your expected load won't be that high I'd just go with the first option, but I would be very interested to see the test results in terms of usability and performance. Here a `sp_getapplock` example:

```
DECLARE @result INT;

EXEC @result = sp_getapplock
  @Resource = 'MySessionsNameForThisApplock'
, @LockMode = 'Exclusive'
, @LockOwner = 'Session';

IF @result < 0
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('Could not get applock - MySessionsNameForThisApplock.', 16, 1);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- do your stuff here but don't forget the overall error handling...

  EXEC @result = sp_releaseapplock
    @Resource = 'MySessionsNameForThisApplock'
  , @LockOwner = 'Session';
END;
```